# calendar.date(bySetting: .day, value: 1, of: Date()) wrongly always adding one month

Tags: swift, calendar

I want to get two dates, the first and last day of current month. Pretty simple. But `date(bySetting: Calendar.Component, value: Int, of: Date)` are not working properly.

Look this piece of code:

When `Date()` prints `2019-04-18 14:11:36 UTC`

```
let calendar = Calendar.current

let firstDayDate = calendar.date(bySetting: .day, value: 1, to: Date())! //2019-05-01 03:00:00 UTC  

let firsDayNextMonth = calendar.date(byAdding: .month, value: 1, to: firstDayDate)! //2019-06-01 03:00:00 UTC   
let lastDayMonthDate = calendar.date(bySetting: .day, value: -1, to: firsDayNextMonth)! //2019-05-31 03:00:00 UTC
```

Look at `firstDayDate` value, day value are setted to 1, but get added 1 to month value.

Please tell me if i forgot something, but for me it looks like a bug

Obs: I now i can do that using `DateComponent`, but if it's a bug, i want to file a bug to apple.

**Edit1:** I'm not asking how to get the first and last day of current month. I know how to do that using other methods, but how i explain ahead, i think there's a bug in `date(byAdding: Calendar.Component, value: Int, to: Date)` method or if i'm not using that properly.

Comment: This is a known bug where `.date(bySetting:value:of:)` searches forward in time. You can use [`.nextDate(after:matching:value:options:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscalendar/1417170-nextdate), searching `.backwards` in time

Comment: @ItaiFerber if this is a known bug, do you know if there is a bug report to apple discussing this?

Comment: @MwcsMac How i describe in "Obs:" i now i can do that in other way, but i find a bug on this method, i'm not asking how to get the first and last day of month, i can do that in other ways.

Comment: It's not really a bug, it's how the method works.

Comment: I understang why that happens and why it's not really a bug, but, for me, it's an issue on the method or its documentation/description. They don't let clearly that it's a forward search, and on the [doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2292915-date) they use a example telling 
>which could be a forwards or backwards move, and not necessarily the nearest[...]

Comment: Yes, there are a few reports, but I’m not sure any of them are on OpenRadar or similar. (Please feel free to file a dupe — can’t hurt!) This is indeed a bug but given the existing behavior being potentially relied upon, it’s possible the only reasonable fix would be to deprecate in favor of a differently-named method.

Comment: @ItaiFerber I'm in agreement, maybe it's the only reasonable thing that apple can do. I'm about to file a bug

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, since i got that this issue it's not necessarily a real bug on method, but it's the way they are setting the component, **searching** the first forward, and not really **setting**, on my perception the method name, description and documentation don't reflect the real feature of the method:

They use a example:

> So for the “set to Thursday” example, find the Thursday in the Week in which the given date resides (which could be a forwards or backwards move, and not necessarily the nearest Thursday).

But they recommend to use other method to get more control of the behavior:

> For more control over the exact behavior, use [nextDate(after:matching:matchingPolicy:behavior:direction:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2293473-nextdate).

So, here is the implementation using this recommended method:

```
let componentDay = DateComponents(day: 1)
let calendar = Calendar.current

let firstDayDate = calendar.nextDate(after: Date(), matching: componentDay, matchingPolicy: .previousTimePreservingSmallerComponents, direction: .backward)!


let firsDayNextMonth = calendar.date(byAdding: .month, value: 1, to: firstDayDate)!
let lastDayMonthDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: firsDayNextMonth)!
```

Comment: Super super super confusing, thank you for the pointer to .nextDate/.backward

Answer (score 1):

Other answer is great, it might also be easier to just use components directly rather than attempting to use the bySetting: interface.

```
fileprivate func beginningOfThisYear() -> Date {
  var comps = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: Date())
  comps.month = 1
  comps.day = 1
  return Calendar.current.date(from: comps)!
}
```